# How to customize the prompt for root?

Tags: bash, root, prompt

If one wants to have a customized prompt, one only has to edit the `.bashrc` file in one's home directory and add `PS1="yourPrompt"` at the very end.

What if one `sudo su` into the root and want to have a customized prompt automatically displayed?

Comment: Since you  shouldn't really have to do much at an interactive root prompt (if anything), it is probably enough to leave it as `#`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To change bash shell options for root, you need to edit/create `/root/.bashrc` with the options you need and switch to root either via regular login or `su -` (which can be called with `sudo`).

Answer (score 0):

In GNU/Linux Fedora 32, run the followings commands to gaining [root privileges or system administrator privileges](https://fedoramagazine.org/howto-use-sudo/).

```
sudo -i
type your owns password
```

If you want e.g. customize your root prompt of your terminal with [powerline](https://fedoramagazine.org/add-power-terminal-powerline/), you must edit `/root/.bashrc` file, then run

```
source /root/.bashrc
```